# Is there any way to delay the fade-in time for intellisense in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just switched to VS2008, and intellisense is even more 'helpful' there than in 2005.

I'm finding it to really break my concentration having it pop up every time I reach the end of a token or key word or whatever.  I have to hit ESC or ignore it and it's *really* annoying.

I've not been able to find a setting to delay its activation.  I do want it, so can't just cripple it, but I'd like it to wait for a second or two pause in my typing to activate.

Anyone know if there is such an option somewhere in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such option exists, but why don't you disable it and use Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+J when needed?

Comment: Nice.  Had no idea those keystrokes existed.  

Could you tell me how to turn off the auto intellisense?  Looking through the options, I saw nothing at all related to settings for it.

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> <your language> -> Intellisense and uncheck "Show completion list after first character is typed"

Comment: Sorry.  I see settings for it for C#, but I'm working in VB.NET and in options > text editor > basic there are none.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look a this forum post about [Recommended Settings for intellisense](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/37612/129697.aspx). Though it seems as of Visual Studio 2005, IntelliSense is now activated by default when the user begins to type, instead of requiring marker characters.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: That does help.  Thanks.  Gets me halfway there.  Unfortunately there are intellisense setting options for C#, but not for VB.NET, which is what I'm working in now.  And this is frustrating - now that I'm aware it annoys me, I can't stop being irritated by it.  It's like suddenly becoming aware of a cut on your tongue.  Once you feel it, you can't stop feeling it.

Comment: Yes, I do belive that the visual basic intellisense is different than C#. Different teams think different options are more important.