# Is there a way to increase the popup delay for Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

I realized today that I spend more time swatting away Intellisense popups than I do using them.

I still want to use Intellisense but I'd like it to show up after a delay (say 1 second). I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper so I might need to change more than one setting.

I don't see any options in `Visual Studio > Options > Text Editor > C# > Intellisense`

I don't see any options in `Resharper > Options > Environment > Intellisense`

There is an [old Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764684/) but it's seven years old. Hopefully there is more recent information.

Comment: Is there any way to delay the *closing* of an intellisense popup? I have trouble keeping it open while moving my cursor into its container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now in VS 2015, there is no such option to set the delay time of the intellisense popup. I have reported [this user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17748394-please-add-an-option-to-set-the-delay-time-that-th) to the VS product team and you can vote it, then we need to wait for the response from the VS product team engineers. For other community members also have the same idea, you can also vote this user voice.

In VS code, I found we can set the delay time through edit the value of the properties ‘**editor.quickSuggestionsDelay’** in the user or workspace setting file to make the intellisense popup delay time like the following screenshot and it works fine. For more detail information, you can check [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace): https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't delay if you hit 'dot' or on parantheses.

Comment: Yep, still pops up immediately after "." or "(", which is a pity. As a workaround, I've turned off the setting `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` so it doesn't open this way. It still does after I start typing after ".", so it's still usable (Ctrl+Space still works as well).

Answer (score 30):

**Editor › Hover: Delay** (`editor.hover.delay` in settings.json)

This is the relevant setting to delay the popup of Intellisense (or other info bubbles) when you hover over something.

**Editor: Quick Suggestions Delay** (`editor.quickSuggestionsDelay` in settings.json)

This setting controls how long it takes to get inline as-you-type suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if there was something in a recent update but I found the intellisense popups were appearing much quicker than before. Changing editor.hover.delay helped.