# Make VSCode intellisense show up only after certain number of characters

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find if there's a way to do it.

I use VScode for writing markdown text. I love the intellisense/autocomplete which builds my word lists and helps me write faster. The one thing I wish I could change is for the autocomplete word lists to show up AFTER I've typed a certain number of characters.

For e.g., let's say I really want the word "guarding"

I'd like the popup only after I've typed guar rather than at g, and then u, etc. This way, I'm utilizing it only for longer words. The popup for every letter from the beginning is kind of annoying.

Is there a way to do it? (I seem to be able to control the delay when to popup,

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684027/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-popup-delay-for-intellisense

Comment: Thanks. I did consider it, but it's annoying now to wait to see what pops up. I'd rather just see them after X characters typed.

Comment: There is no VS Code setting for this but it sounds like a good candidate for an extension. Checkout the [extension authoring docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) to get started

Comment: Notepad++ has had this option for a very long time. Do the people creating IntelliSense not use VS or VS Code? If they did, surely many of them would be annoyed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is currently not possible but I opened a feature request [on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204535). Please upvote [on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204535) it if you are interested in this feature.

Comment: Upvote is only for correct answers...

Comment: @Sreemat I meant to say that everyone who is interested in the feature should upvote the linked github issue.